# FileNotFoundException JoanZapata/PDFView Library Android

Tags: android, pdf-viewer

I've been trying to display a PDF using the PDFView Library.

The PDF is first downloaded and saved into internal memory

My Logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.amfstudios.echomagazine/com.amfstudios.PDFViewer}: com.joanzapata.pdfview.exception.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.amfstudios.echomagazine/app_magPDF/PDF_1.pdf does not exist.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2314)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
 Caused by: com.joanzapata.pdfview.exception.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.amfstudios.echomagazine/app_magPDF/PDF_1.pdf does not exist.
        at com.joanzapata.pdfview.PDFView.fromAsset(PDFView.java:905)
        at com.amfstudios.PDFViewer.onCreate(PDFViewer.java:79)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5953)
```

Although using Log I was able to see that the downloaded file was saved with the same path as the one shown in the FileNotFoundException

The save is within a fragment, and read from an activity.

Comment: If you have a solution please put it in the answer box provided, or delete the question. This is better than editing the word "solved" into the question.